# Getting duplicate rows when merging two data frames in R, should I merge or join these 2 dataframes?

Tags: r

I am trying to get every pitch thrown from Justin Verlander on May 07 2011 by joining or merging 2 data frames (`at_bat` , `pitch`) from the `pitchRx` library, however when I use the function multiple rows repeat. I should have somewhere around 100+ (for the total of number of pitches he threw during that game). Is it even possible to merge or join these 2 dataframes to get my desired result?

```
library("Lahman")
library("pitchRx")
library("ggplot2")
library("tidyverse")
library("dplyr")

pitching_05_07_2011<-scrape(start="2011-05-07", end="2011-05-07")


atbats<-pitching_05_07_2011$atbat
pitches<-pitching_05_07_2011$pitch

head(atbats)
head(pitches)

verlander_nohitter<-filter(atbats,atbats$pitcher_name=="Justin Verlander")
verlander_nohitter



pitching_atbats<-merge(verlander_nohitter,pitches,by="url")
pitching_atbats
```

Comment: There are 27 rows in `verlander_nohitter`, all with the same url. We can see that `sum(pitches$url == verlander_nohitter$url[1])` gives 280 so there are 280 rows in `pitches` with that url. 27 * 280 gives you the 7560 rows in `pitching_atbats`. I'm not clear on what the actual desired result is, but this is why you are getting the result you have.

Comment: so the result I am looking for is to get all the pitches that Justin Verlander threw on May 07 2011: the `pitches` dataframe has all the pitches for all the pitches that threw on that day however, it does not show what pitcher threw what pitches, which is why im trying to merge so i can get the `pitches` dataframe to only contain values for Justin Verlander by using the `at bats` data frame

Comment: the `verlander_nohitter` contains the 27 outs he recorded that day but it doesnt show all the pitches he threw which is what I want for only Justin Verlander

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried the function duplicated() to either identify or eliminate duplicates? For example, in this simple example:

```
a <- c(rep(sample(letters[1:10], 5),2))
a
[1] "e" "a" "b" "h" "d" "e" "a" "b" "h" "d"
```

you get a number of duplicates. You can identify and remove them thus:

```
a_clean <- a[!duplicated(a)]
a_clean
[1] "e" "a" "b" "h" "d"
```

Comment: I tried using this but could not get it to work thanks

Comment: If you can give me a clearer idea of your data set or would share your data or some subset of it, then I could probably help you better.

Comment: so the `scrape` function here limits the 5 datasets from the `pitchRx` library to any timeframe, i.e. `pitching_05_07_2011`. Now I have 5 data frames from the library `pitchRx`;`atbat pitch action po runner`. Now, I would either like to merge or join 2 of the 5 data frames (`at bat pitch`).

Comment: My goal with these 2 data frames is to filter them for one specific pitcher.  (Justin Verlander) and the specific pitches he threw that day. The only problem is only ONE of these 2 dataframes contains a pitcher name, that being the `at bat` data frame, which has the column `pitcher_name`. Now that I have a name, I want to `merge` or `join` the `at bat` data frame with the `pitch` data frame in an attempt to retrieve all the pitches that Justin Verlander threw on that day. (Note, the `pitch` data frame contains all the pitches that were thrown on that day).

Comment: This data is available in the `pitchRx` library. It has to be `scrape`d first, to get the 5 dataframes (`at bat pitch po runner action`) for the desired time frame, as it would take hours to load the entire dataset, which has data since 2008.

Comment: It'd be of great help if you could define some mock data frames structured along the lines of your real data frames, so one doesn't need to dive deep into all of your apparently extensive data but merely deal with your problem?